# How can I influence the elements plotted in a BubbleChart depending on the tuple plotted?

Tags: plotting

In a `BubbleChart`, how can I influence the elements plotted depending on a value in the tuple plotted?

I want to create a `BubbleChart` from the following data:

```
 lines = {{1, 10, 2}, {2, 15, 1}, {3, 27, 4}, {4, 35, 2}}
```

but instead of the bubbles, I want to draw a line as long as `z`.

Comment: had to reward myself by smarty-pantsing the answer right away, as it took some reading the documentation. Sadly, the predictive interface did not do my homework for me...

Answer (score 3):

`ChartElementFunction` to the rescue! It not only has a couple of builtin functions to change the plotted elements

```
ChartElementData["BubbleChart"]

{"Bubble", "FadingBubble", "GradientBubble", "MarkerBubble", \
"NoiseBubble", "OscillatingBubble", "PolyhedronBubble", \
"SphereBubble", "SquareWaveBubble", "TriangleWaveBubble"}
```

but it's also possible to define a custom function that will be fed by `BubbleChart`. For each plotted tuple, it receives [*region*, *values*, *metadata*] and can be used to plot lines like

```
lines = {{1, 10, 2}, {2, 15, 1}, {3, 27, 4}, {4, 35, 2}}
doline[___, {x_, y_, z_}, ___] :=
 Line[{{x, y}, {x + z, y}}]
BubbleChart[lines, ChartElementFunction -> doline]
```

[image]