# Arguments for ChartElementFunction

Tags: functions, options, plotting

I was reading the documentation for [`BubbleChart`](https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BubbleChart.html) and I saw this example

```
DataDrilldownBubble[{{xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, ymax_}}, v_, {meta_}, style___] := PopupWindow[
  Polygon[{{xmin, ymin}, {xmax, ymax}, {xmin, ymax}, {xmax, ymin}}], PieChart[meta]]

DataDrilldownBubble[{{xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, ymax_}}, y_, ___] := Rectangle[
 {xmin, ymin}, {xmax, ymax}]

BubbleChart[{{1, 0, 1} -> Range[5], {0, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 3} -> RandomReal[1, 10]}, 
            ChartElementFunction -> DataDrilldownBubble]
```

How exactly the `ChartElementFunction` works? Which arguments are passed to it?

In this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/36986/11277) the claim is that the arguments are  [`region`, `values`, `metadata`]. The use of `style___` in the documentation may suggest that there is another optional argument.

Is there an official documentation for that? How are exactly the metadata defined? [The Mathematica help for `ChartElementFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ChartElementFunction.html) is not very helpful here.

In the above examples metadata are given by the lists `Range[5]` and `RandomReal[1, 10]` respectively

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

As per advice from Kuba, my answer was terse. Also see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/43504/1997) re: an instructive use of `DynamicWrapper` by Kuba.

Here is a toy example for illustrative purposes:

```
data = {{{1, 2, 3} -> "apple", {2, 3, 4} -> "banana"} -> 
    "fruit", {{3, 4, 5} -> "celery"} -> "vegetable"};
va = "";
co["fruit"] := Red;
co["vegetable"] := Yellow;
g[___, {x_, y_, z_}, meta_] := 
 DynamicWrapper[{co[First@meta], Disk[{x, y}, z/40]}, 
  If[CurrentValue["MouseOver"], 
   va = Style[Row[{meta[[1]], ": ", meta[[2]]}], 12, 
     FontFamily -> "Kartika", Blue], va = ""]]
Column[{BubbleChart[data, ChartElementFunction -> g], Dynamic@va}, 
 Alignment -> Center]
```

[image]

This follows the documentation for use of `ChartElementFunction` for `BubbleChart`. The structure of the data determines how the metadata is extracted. I wished to illustrate this with the toy example showing the relationship between data structure and `ChartElementFunction`. I hope this motivates more creative functions than my own.

Comment: You could add some explanation :)

Comment: @Kuba you are correct. As you see I have started playing with  `DynamicWrapper` exploiting your code from http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/43504/1997

Comment: I see :) I think OP (and me too) missed that in Details in Options there is a desctiption that `form_i->m_i` syntax is responsible for this what is a metadata. Maybe worth to stress it in the answer.